# Convert PHP array to JSON using multi dimentional arrays

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am trying to convert this php array to a json. This is my code:

```
$c = array();
$c = array(
$c['cronjobs'] = array(
    'id'=>1189515,
    'groupId'=>12379,
    ),
);
$json = json_encode($c);
echo $json;
```

This is the output I'd like to acieve:
`{"cronjobs":[{"id":1186437,"groupId":12379]}`

Though using the above code this is what I am getting
`[{"id":1189515,"groupId":12379}]`

The `[{"cronjobs"`part is not appearing.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get the result that you want (just wrap an array around the id, groupId array):

```
<?php
     $c = array();
     $c['cronjobs'] = array(array(
         'id'=>1189515,
         'groupId'=>12379,
     ));

     echo json_encode($c);
     // result {"cronjobs":[{"id":1189515,"groupId":12379}]}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you need to format your array:

```
$c = array(); // declare the array
$c['cronjobs'] = array( // populate the array
    'id'=>1189515,
    'groupId'=>12379,
);
$json = json_encode($c); // json_encode it
echo $json;
```

There is no need for `$c = array($c['cronjob']);` (which was what you were doing).

Comment: Hi. I'm not getting the square brackets -  `[{"id":1189515,"groupId":12379}]`

Comment: @xltmt: What do you mean?

Comment: Hi, when I tried your code I am getting `{"cronjobs":{"id":1189515,"groupId":12379}}` I need to out put `**[**{"cronjobs":{"id":1189515,"groupId":12379}**]**}`. There are two square brackets [] between the two outputs. They're between the asterisks **

Comment: @xltmt: You have misplaced your brackets. This is no valid JSON.

Comment: I formatted my code according to your suggestion. I never worked with JSON before so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
$c = array('cronjobs' => array());

$c['cronjobs'][] = array('id' => 1189515, 'groupId' => 12379);
//$c['cronjobs'][] = array('id' => 1234, 'groupId' => 4321);

$json = json_encode($c);
echo $json;
```

Cronjobs needs to contain an array of cronjob objects/arrays

Could also be written using one statement, like this:

```
$c = array('cronjobs' => array(
    array('id' => 1189515, 'groupId' => 12379),
    array('id' => 1234, 'groupId' => 4321)
));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that in PHP `array` is used to represent both JSON objects and JSON lists hence the confusion. Consider the following code:

```
$cronjob = array(
    'id' => 1189515,
    'groupId' => 12379
);
echo json_encode($cronjob);
// {"id":1189515,"groupID":12379"}
```

As you can see this represents a single object. So we'll create a list of objects:

```
$cronjobs = array($cronjob);
echo json_encode($cronjobs);
// [{"id":1189515,"groupID":12379"}]
```

This is now a list as expected. Now the parent object:

```
$c = array(
    'cronjobs' => $cronjobs
);
echo json_encode($c);
// {"cronjobs":[{"id":1189515,"groupID":12379"}]}
```

Answer (score -1):

In **JSON** there is a **name: value** pair system

```js
{
  "firstName": "John",
  "lastName": "Smith",
  "isAlive": true,
  "age": 25,
  "address": {
    "streetAddress": "21 2nd Street",
    "city": "New York",
    "state": "NY",
    "postalCode": "10021-3100"
  },
  "phoneNumbers": [
    {
      "type": "home",
      "number": "212 555-1234"
    },
    {
      "type": "office",
      "number": "646 555-4567"
    }
  ],
  "children": [],
  "spouse": null
}
```

if you want to achieve like `{"cronjobs":[{"id":1186437,"groupId":12379]}` then the array must be named like the following in **`PHP`**:

```
$c['cronjobs'] = array(
'id'=>1189515,
'groupId'=>12379,
);

$json = json_encode($c);
echo $json;
```